# HTML/CSS form as letter, textarea postioning

Tags: html, css, forms, web, textarea

i got problem with form who's look like letter, i want to create something like this

```
text                ......input.........
text                ......input.........
text                ......textarea......
......textarea............textarea......
......textarea............textarea......
......textarea............textarea......
```

for this moment, textarea going down after 3line text, or when i am trying do something else, its actually replace text on third line... how should i do this to make it worth? Ty for any respond

Comment: Welcome to SO you may need to check this site http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist and then edit your question. Help us to help you

Comment: Here's help: http://alistapart.com/article/prettyaccessibleforms